# Can Sequelize handle multiple keys that is associated with one table?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Let's say I have a table called Table1. There are 3 business ids associated to one Business table.

```
Table1
---------
idBusiness1, idBusiness2, idBusiness3, etc.

Business
---------
idBusiness, Name
```

Is there a way to associate the two tables above to create a Sequelize query (other than raw query) to pull back the name of all 3 businesses?

The SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, B1.Name AS 'Business1', B2.Name AS 'Business2'
FROM
    Table1 t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Business b1 ON idBusiness1 = b1.idBusiness
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Business b2 ON idBusiness2 = b2.idBusiness
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean Table1 contains a field idBusiness with the idBusiness1, idBusiness2, idBusiness3, ... values, what you want to achieve in SQL format is

```
db.seq.query('
SELECT * FROM Business 
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.idBusiness = Business.idBusiness ').success(function(rows) {
    res.json(rows);
});
```

Using ORM format you would use eager loading with the `include` parameter:

```
Table1.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Business,
        required: true
    }]
}).then(results => {
     /* ... */
}.);
```

If you mean you have 3 different fields, and want to get the names of business of id equal to at least one of them:

```
SELECT * from Business
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Business.idBusiness IN (Table1.idBusiness1, Table1.idBusiness2, Table1.idBusiness3)
```

In ORM format the simplest method I can think of is

```
Business.findAll({
    where: { id: list }
}
```

Where you would get all ids from Table1 from a findAll query, and transform the result into an array of all those ids. I guess the result of Table1.findAll{} would be of format

```
 [{idBusiness1: 1, idBusiness2: 2, idBusiness3: 3}, {idBusiness1: 42, idBusiness2: 32, idBusiness: 70}]
```

So with a little code you iterate over this list to form another

```
finalList = [];
list.forEach((item) => {
    finalList.push(item.idBusiness1)
    finalList.push(item.idBusiness2)
    finalList.push(item.idBusiness3)
}
```

If you have more than 3 fields in Table1, you can iterate over the properties of the Javascript object to generalize those 3 pushes. Let me know if that's the case and you need help with it.

**Update:**

Since OP clarified, setting `required:false` in the query will turn the inner joins into left (outer) joins.

When you add a where option, it automatically sets required to true, which turns the join into an inner join. See the description of param `options.include[].where` at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#findalloptions-promisearrayinstance.

It does not seem possible in Sequelize syntax to join on the same table, you would include the same table as the one you are calling the find on. That is why Sequelize supports raw queries in those specific cases...

Comment: I updated my answer as well, unfortunately it does not seem possible to join on the same table you're querying in sequelize syntax. Raw query looks like it's the way to go